# `ThisType` does not affect the `this` in the method inside a wrapper

Tags: typescript, this, throttling

I want to access `this.data.a` in the code below, and the compiler can infer the type of `this.data.a` as number as expected.

```js
function defineComponent<T, U>(
  options: {
    data: T;
    methods: U;
  } & ThisType<{ data: T }>
): void {}

defineComponent({
  data: {
    a: 1,
  },
  methods: {
    fn() {
      console.log(this.data.a)
    },
  },
});
```

However, when I want to wrap the `fn()` with `throttle()`, I cannot access the this, because the compiler told me `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

```js
function defineComponent<T, U>(
  options: {
    data: T;
    methods: U;
  } & ThisType<{ data: T }>
): void {}

function throttle<T extends Function>(fn: T, time: number) {
  return fn;
}

defineComponent({
  data: {
    a: 1,
  },
  methods: {
    fn: throttle(function () {
      console.log(this.data.a)
    }, 1000),
  },
});
```

So how can I make compiler infer the type of this in `fn()` as the `ThisType` for  `options`? In Kotlin, I can use `this@xxx` to specify which `this` I want to use, but it's not supported in TS. Maybe I can write like `thorottle(function(this: { data: a }) { /* ... */}, 1000)`, but it's too redundant to write the function which the compiler should have done for the developers. I also tried `throttle<typeof this>()`, however, it cannot infer the type of `this`, either.

Comment: TS's contextual typing is fragile (see [this q](//stackoverflow.com/q/64650888/2887218) for example); it's a design limitation. `ThisType<T>` adds a contextual type to `this` inside the object, but it does not reach into function calls inside that. In cases like this you'll have to annotate, even if the compiler "should" have done that already (it's easy to say it "should" do something but much harder to implement a compiler to do everything it "should" do).  As shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WPKnKm).  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz 
For `fn2`, I have to annotate the type, but it's troublesome when there are lots of methods or data, so it does not satisfy my requirements. For `fn3`, `throttle()` returns a function, and the returned function is called instantly, so the `fn3` should return the `void` (the returned type of `fn`), which means it does not work, either.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't meet your requirements; I'm saying that your requirements cannot be met because TS doesn't propagate contextual typing the way you want it to.  It's a design limitation of the language.  So, neglecting `fn3` (which is not identical semantically to your desired version), something like `fn2` is the best you can do.  Does that fully address the question (i.e., "how can I do X", "you can't, because Y"), or am I missing something about what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer, but sadly it doesn't solve my problem. Because the reason why I wrote this function is to reduce the type definition. Currently my solution is like this:
`defineComponent({ methods: { fn() { /* ... */ }}, lifetimes: { created() {this.fn = throttle(this.fn, 1000 )} } });` Add a `created()` method in the internal implementation of `defineComponent`, and call it when the component is created to reassign the `fn`to `throttle(fn)`